# Partial XML parsing using google-api-java-client (now google-http-java-client) possible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-java-client

I have some quick questions regarding XML parsing:

1. Is it possible to parse, as a Java type, specific XML elements that
   are positioned in various deep levels of the XML document hierarchy
   without having to map each ancestor element to corresponding java
   type and parsing it? In other words parsing a 'deep_nested_element'
   as DeepNestedElement.class without the need of parsing
   'root_element' as Root.class?
2. Is it possible to parse, as a Java type, specific XML elements that
   have two attributes which have equal values, in other words parsing
   <person name="**John**" nickname="**John**"/> and not parsing
   <person name="Jack" nickname="Jack The Ripper"/>?

Regards,
Bonev

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is for both questions. Two links: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html 
and
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp .

Comment: didn't notice the "(...) as Java Type (...)". For this i don't know any solution. My answer depends on you having to create the Java Types to old the parsed data.